# How to have different Backgrounds and colors for dividers in GridView?

Tags: android, background, android-gridview, divider

I wish to keep different colors for the divider and background in my GridView. Or I would like to hide the background color visible around the Gridview. I tried changing layout_margin & padding parameters, but that did not change anything. Following is the xml layout for my GridView.

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gvFree" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
           android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_col_wd"
           android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
           android:layout_margin="-5dp"
           android:padding="-5dp"
           android:numColumns="auto_fit"
           android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
           android:gravity="fill"
           android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
           android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
           ></GridView>
```

Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Remove spacings and create borders for your rows

Comment: there are some solutions about dividers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109126/android-gridview-row-dividers-separators

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109126/android-gridview-row-dividers-separators   check this out

Comment: we can add GridView background and divider color for GridView.