# Android Data table : does it exist?

Tags: android

Android design documentation tells about "Data tables", which offer a lot of interesting features (https://material.google.com/components/data-tables.html).
Unfortunately, in the latest version of Android studio as of 25:10:2016, "Data table" component is not implemented. I read the StackOverflow answer (2015) that says to use something else. But I would like to know if this implementation exists somewhere in android studio in a place I dont know, or if it is not quite ready and will exist soon, or if it will never exist. In that case it would be better to strip off that "Data table" from the design documentation.

Comment: Android Studio is just an IDE designed to make working with these projects easier. Its not the same as the API itself. What Android SDK version does your app use?

Comment: You mention this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130838/how-to-implement-data-tables-material-design-component-in-android

Comment: I use studio 2.2.2 and sdk 6.0

Comment: Yes I mentionned that link

Answer (score 1):

Not all components described in the Material design specifications are directly mapped to a `View` provided in the SDK. Most are just guidelines you should follow when creating the presentation layer of your app :-)

Providing a `View` makes sense for some of the components that are special or potentially memory heavy, such as `CardView` or the `FloatingActionButton`. But it also limits the user, so in most cases the platform provides less specific tools you can use to build exactly the thing you want :-)

As for "data tables", this can be easily implemented using a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a specific adapter.

Comment: I understand your point. I will try if I can realize all the features "promised" by "Data table" with "RecyclerView".