# Is TableLayout still useful?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Im working on Android Studio and I use book from 2015 to learn it. There are some differences but Im fine with dealing with them. But I stopped because of TableLayout. I try to convert original ConstraintLayout into TableLayout but when I do so, I can't place buttons, text boxes etc. on design page. I searched through official tutorial and there is no such thing as TableLayout. Is it still functioning?

Answer (score 1):

Table Layout is still a valid UI component in android.
However a new component called Data Table is introduced which is more compatible with Material design.
You can see this [good stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130838/how-to-implement-data-tables-material-design-component-in-android) about data table and also this [link](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html)