# How to show a vertical line between columns of a grid layout in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gridlayout

I am making a native android app, I want to draw a **vertical line between two columns** in a **grid-layout**, is there any way i can do this ??
In the following screenshot, you can see the lines between cells and between the column. Basically, i just want to display the grid with my own custom style. [This is the link to see the screenshots, apparently stack wont let me post a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws5so.jpg)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23891978/2826147)

Comment: Go below link you may find your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109126/android-gridview-row-dividers-separators

Comment: A lot of good solutions. what do you think if we went 1px ppl instead of 1dp. the line will look nice and thinner on devices with high specs. does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **verticalSpacing** in your grid layout and set GridView background as the color of line you want.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DADADA"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Vertical line like this -

```
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" />
```

You can set the height as per requirement and can add margin to the above **View** if required

Comment: I use this solution usually. but, I don't like it for one reason. the line is thik and doesn't look nice. how we can do a thinner line than 1 dp.

Comment: i am using grid view layout

Comment: even that you use a grid layout. you can put it in a framelayout along with this suggested view.

Comment: @hasan83 , you must be having an XML layout for grid items. Just use this code there, you will get a vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

if you use two LinearLayouts side by side you can use the frameworks divider function with an ease:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:divider="?android:listDivider"
    android:dividerPadding="2.5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:weightSum="2" > ... </LinearLayout>
```

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="?android:listDivider"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:weightSum="1" >
       <GridLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
           android:rowCount="2"
           android:columnCount="1">
           <TextView
               android:text="Qty"
               />
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtQtyProduct"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:text="1"/>

       </GridLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
```