# How to set divider in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23891978/4850591) to set dividers in my gridview but the issue i am getting five items from server and set in my gridview,but in my last griditem it display grey box.  See this Output https://imageshack.com/i/poKIvv1Up

Comment: And what should it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Best_Product extends BaseAdapter {
    View gridView;
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Function_List fun_lib = new Function_List();
    public Best_Product(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> json_value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context = c;
        MyArr = json_value;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int total_size = MyArr.size();
        Log.d("size of item", "" + MyArr.size());
            if((MyArr.size()%2)==0)
            {
                // do nothing 
            }
            else
            {
                total_size = MyArr.size()+1;
            }

        return total_size;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashMap<String, String> mapAtPostion = MyArr.get(position);
        return Long.valueOf(MyArr.get(position).get("product_id"));

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        RelativeLayout background_color; // this will be the Relativelayout of the content of GridView. you will be set backgroud color of last item 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (view == null) {
                view = new View(context);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_best_collection_content, parent, false);
                background_color = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.bckground);
                    //checking last item of the array
                if(position ==MyArr.size()-1)
                {
                    //change the last item background color
                    background_color.setBackgroundColor();
                }
                else
                {
                        // do the work here 
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Please try this code and let me know any problem,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

that's the `default` behaviour, it should show the `background` "empty space" since there is no more `rows` to be inserted in `row` number 6.
if i were you, i had get rid of `GridView` and use `RecyclerView` and use `StaggeredLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager` to have more controls over the span counts and could modify them accordingly.

Comment: yes i agree that it will be easy with recycler but why not with gridview?

Comment: @AdityaVyas cause this is common and usual behavior of GridView and it's impossible to do this, only to overwrite GridView elemen